# Limit Cycle at $r=1$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider the non-linear ODE
$$u''+(u^2+u'^2-1)u'+u=0.$$ Transforming this to polar coordinates:
$$r'=-(r^2-1)r\sin^2(\theta),$$
$$\theta'=-\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)(r^2-1)-1.$$

> If we consider an annulus (trapping region), $\frac{1}{2}<x^2+y^2<2,$ how do we deal with the $\sin^2(\theta)$ term?

We can use the fact that $$\sin^2(\theta)=\frac{1-\cos(2\theta)}{2}.$$

If we take $\cos(2\theta)=-1\implies r'>0$ for $r<\frac{1}{2}$ and $r'<0$ for $r>2$.
**But**, if we take $\cos(2\theta)=1\implies r'=0$ for $r<\frac{1}{2}$ and $r'=0$ for $r>2$.

Ideally $r'$ should point towards the annular region for both cases. I can't see an error in my logic.

Comment: Is the last term in $θ'$ correct? $$θ'=\frac{xy'-x'y}{r^2}=\frac{uu''-u'^2}{r^2}=-1+\frac{u(u''+u)}{r^2}=-1-(r^2-1)\sinθ\cosθ.$$

Comment: @LutzL Yes, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume unit speed for the flow system (primes denote differentiation with respect to arc distance). If $\psi$ is angle the streamline makes to radius vector then from the given relations for $r^{'}$ and $\theta^{'}$

$$ \tan \psi = \dfrac{r d\theta}{dr}= \dfrac{r\theta^{'}}{r{'} }=\dfrac {1+\sin \theta \cos \theta \,(r^2-1)}{(r^2-1)\, {\sin ^2\theta}} $$

which has vanishing denominator at $r=1 $ or $ \psi= \pm\pi/2 $ *at any $\theta$* in the flow. That is consider $\theta$ *as fixed* and $r$ as variable. The flow direction does not change, i.e., the sign of slope of the tangent remains same:

[image: Limit Cycle]

$r=1$ represents *a circular asymptote* of the Limit Cycle. It  is also shown in the  $(r,\,\tan \psi) $ graph as the green asymptote. The entire flow has either clockwise or anti-clockwise angular velocity on both sides of the circular asymptote.

Comment: As you can see in the stream plot in the answer of Cesareo, the flow is always clockwise. Also, you are using the uncorrected formula for the angular velocity $θ'$.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I meant. It should not matter as long as $ r=1$ is a pole and so an  asymptote. However re- plotted to your  $\theta^{'}$ correction.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

Putting in the form

$$
\dot u_1 = u_2\\
\dot u_2 = -(u_1^2+u_2^2-1)u_2 - u_1
$$

then

$$
\frac 12(u_1^2+u_2^2)' = -u_2^2(u_1^2+u_2^2-1)
$$

and the stream plot gives

[image]

NOTE

When $u_1^2+u_2^2 = 1$ then $\dot u_1 = u_2$ and also

$$
2u_1\dot u_1 +2u_2\dot u_2 = 0\Rightarrow \dot u_2 = - u_1
$$

and those points have the dynamics dictated by

$$
\dot u_1 = u_2\\
\dot u_2 = -u_1
$$

which describes concentric circles.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. I did this initially, but do not see how this helps. Should I have not used polar coordinates?

Comment: @Bell   As you can verify, any point inside the unit circle has an increasing module while any point outside that same circle has a decreasing module.

Answer (score 1):

Consider
$$
\frac{d}{dt}|r-1|={\rm sign}(r-1)r'=-|r-1|r(r+1)\sin^2θ.
$$
This is always non-positive for $r>0$. And as no solution can stay at $θ=k\pi$, the radius will always move towards $r=1$ over finite time steps..